# Regex replace element unless there is another match on same line and before match

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing some work which rewrites sql queries from some users at my company. One of the things we are doing to rewrite these queries is replacing `.`'s surrounded by any kind of whitespace with a `.` surrounded by no whitespace (using the simple regex `\s*\.\s*`).

However, I've run into an issue where an incoming query contains a comment like so:

```
)
  , wcr AS -- hello I am a comment that ends in a period.
(
```

which then formats it like below, which makes the query fail.

```
)
  , wcr AS -- hello I am a comment that ends in a period.(
```

I cannot think of any regex that would do the correct replacement that I am looking for - that is, replace the whitespace surrounded period with one not surrounded by whitespace only if there is not `--` preceding the `.` on the same row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `re.sub(r'--.*|(\s*\.\s*)', lambda x: '.' if x.group(1) else x.group(), text)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you wanted spaces or tabs surrounding a `.` to be replaced, but won't consider the `\n` to be such whitespace.  `\s` is all of `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` in Python.

You could replace `[ \t]*\.[ \t]*` (zero or more space or tab characters on either side), with just the `.`

Comment: This works great! Fits simply into what I was using already. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This regex will find the lines you want and capture the them if you use the g (global) flag:

```
^  , wcr AS (?<!-- )([^\-]*)$
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/0LYWgo/1/

I would then use `string replace` in your favorite programming language to get rid of spaces around the dots.